# flex checkbox group

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I need to use checkbox as radiobutton.
In my case I'd like to define a checkbox group but I don't know why.
If I select one checkbox, I'd like that other checkbox are deselecting

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to use a RadioButton / RadioButtonGroup instead of Checkboxes?

Comment: Why don't you just re-skin the radio button to look like a checkbox?

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices Suggestion would definitely be the easiest solution. However, I think this is a very bad idea from a user experience point of view. Users expect these round buttons with bullets and these square buttons with ckeckmarks to behave a certain way. If you turn that around, you will confuse them.

Comment: @RIAstar - I agree, but that's essentially the question at hand, how to make my radio buttons look like checkboxes. (or how to make my checkboxes work like radio buttons).

Comment: indeed re-skin radiobutton may be a solution, I try to do that

Comment: @Flex60460 is there any reasons why you would like to have a checkbox act as a radio button? I hope next time you will not want a button which can be used instead of scroll bar... :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a static amount of radio buttons you need, you could use Spark States.

```
<s:states>
    <s:State name="check1"/>
    <s:Stage name="check2"/>
</s:States>

<s:CheckBox selected="false" selected.check1="true" click="currentState='check1'"/>
<s:CheckBox selected="false" selected.check2="true" click="currentState='check2'"/>
```

When you click the first one, it triggers the "check1" state in which the first check box is selected and the other is unselected. Clicking the second one does the opposite. Obviously, this is not as flexible as some would hope. But if it's for an interface element (such as an options menu), it's perfect.

States are incredibly useful if you understand how and when to use them. This past weekend, I created an [all-Flex slideshow](http://flexsupreme.com/2012/08/25/the-all-flex-slideshow/) using them and it is a great example of how powerful that simple little array can be.

EDIT: I just threw together a simple app to test this, and it doesn't look like it will work using click. I'm sure you could tinker with another event to get it to work, though. Sorry this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `RadioButton`s, but if you really wanted to do it, I'd take LondonDrugs_MediaServices approach.

`CheckBox` and `RadioButton` both extend from `ToggleButtonBase`.

Create your own `CheckBoxRadioButtonSkin`. Copy the `CheckBoxSkin` to it and rename the `hostComponent`.

Then use this skin on your `radioButton` to make it appear to be checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a requirement like this before and I used a Datagrid with Checkbox inside as itemRenderer.

I subclassed the Checkbox, overrode `data` getter so that each time it is clicked all the items of Datagrid are unselected, unchecked except for him. This method acquired some advantages:

1. Flexible to add number of options programmaticcally.
2. Display title of option group or not.
3. Enable to use scrollbar if there is a limit of space.

Hope the solution is what you are looking for.